# How to path through an entire array, check for a String, delete it, then return it

Tags: java

```
public Cylinder deleteCylinder(String listNameIn) {
    Cylinder result = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < cylinderCount; i++) {
        if (list[i].getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(listNameIn)) {
            for (int j = i; j < cylinderCount - 1; j++) {
                list[j] = list[j + 1];
            }
            result = list[cylinderCount - 1]; 
            cylinderCount--;
            System.out.println("\t\"" + listNameIn + "\" deleted" + "\n");       
        }
        else
            System.out.println("\t\"" + listNameIn + "\" not found" + "\n");     
    }
    return result;
}
```

If I load in a file that contains cylinders with the name "Small Example" "Medium Example" "Large Example" and "Really Large Example" in that order and then try to delete large example it will print out

"Large Example" not found

"Large Example" not found

"Large Example" deleted

Any advice on how to fix this?

Edit: Part of an earlier project, we originally used ArrayList but had to change it to array

Got it, thanks you guys. This was the right code:

```
public Cylinder deleteCylinder(String listNameIn) {

   Cylinder result = null;

  for (int i = 0; i < cylinderCount; i++) {
     if (list[i].getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(listNameIn)) {
        result = list[i];
        for (int j = i; j < cylinderCount - 1; j++) {
           list[j] = list[j + 1];
        }
        result = list[cylinderCount - 1]; 
        cylinderCount--;
        System.out.println("\t\"" + listNameIn + "\" deleted" + "\n");
        return result;

     }                    

  }
  System.out.println("\t\"" + listNameIn + "\" not found" + "\n");
  return result;
```

}

Comment: Well, you're currently printing out either "deleted" or "not found" on every iteration... in other words, for as many items as you've currently got. I strongly suspect you don't want to print "not found" unless you get to the end without finding anything. If you just return `result` as soon as you've deleted the item (which would be easier with a list, btw) you can then print "not found" *after* the loop.

Comment: Besides: consider to use ArrayList instead of array. You can't delete an entry from an array; as the number of elements in your array will stay the same. You code will fill those slots with copies of other existing elements. If you would be using ArrayList, you can do a real "remove that index"; ending up with a list which size is smaller by one.

Comment: With this code, "result" will always be the last Cylinder in the original array. it should be set to list[I] before executing the inner loop.  Also, this code will delete all Cylinders with the name listNameIn